# Microsoft Azure VM Metric suddenly stop

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, metrics

Suddenly I stopped receiving CPU and the other normal metric on 2 of my VMs and therefore the scale function wasn't operating. Did something change that I need to enable something for this to work? I went onto portal and turned on Diagnosticians including Basic metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen multiple times as well, the availability of the metrics is just not very reliable. They usually come back after a while.